# Url changed in custom tabs

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I'm using [ChromeSafariBrowser](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview#chromesafaribrowser-class), I want to know when redirect Url changes in my browser, 
in chrome, getting the changes with [Uni_Links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) like this :

```
getLinksStream().listen((String url) {
    print("url changed: $url");

  }, onError: (error) {
    print("error $error");

  });
```

but it's not fired with other custom tabs, like Firefox.

is there any way to find out when URL changes in custom tabs?

Comment: did you got solution